# Do I need to use certbot if I have an SSL certificate from my domain registrar?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an SSL certificate under my domain registrar (Porkbun). I also installed Nginx on my VPS (Vultr) running Ubuntu 19.10. HTTPS doesn't seem to be working at the moment.

Do I need to install the SSL certificate in my server? If I do, do I need to use certbot to get an SSL certificate for my server, or do I download the one from the domain registrar?

Comment: I think this could be helpful: https://kb.porkbun.com/article/71-how-your-free-ssl-certificate-works

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @j.chan interesting read - its disgusting to me how a service like that takes credit for the hard work of EFF, all while requiring you use their name servers to take advantage of a free service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to speak to your registrar, as only they can accurately advise you about their systems. That said, there are a few things I can say which might help -

1. Certbot is associated with LetsEncrypt - and typically only used on conjunction with their keys. Letsencrypy is different to most SSL cert providers in as much as they only provide certs with a validity period of 3/months, and use certbot to renew them automatically.   If your provider is providing you with certs (rather then facilitating Letsencrypt/certbot which is free,  BTW) then you don't use certbot.
2. Most providers who provide you with a cert do so for a period of 1 year or longer. Typically these certs are manually installed on your server. They do not use certbot.   You normally need to pay for these certs.